# How can I render a Dojo dynamic Chart demo?

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I'm trying to render http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/dynamicChart/demo.html. Now I have all the resources from http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/ and I have fixed all the path of the links inside every files. It just doesn't work. I'm putting code at below: 
demo.html--

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Dojo/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true,parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src.js"></script>
---
---
---
<select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="plot" onChange="changePlot()">
                <option value="Columns">Columns</option>
                <option value="ClusteredColumns">ClusteredColumns</option>
                <option value="StackedColumns">StackedColumns</option>
                <option value="Bars">Bars</option>
                <option value="ClusteredBars">ClusteredBars</option>
                <option value="StackedBars">StackedBars</option>
                <option value="Areas">Areas</option>
                <option value="StackedAreas">StackedAreas</option>
                <option value="Pie">Pie</option>
            </select>
```

demo.profile.js

```
dependencies = {
    layers: [
        {
            name: "../dynamicChart/src.js",
            resourceName: "demos.dynamicChart.src",
            dependencies: [
                "dynamicChart.src"
            ]
        }
    ],

    prefixes: [
        [ "dijit", "/Dojo/dojo-release-1.6.1/dijit" ],
        [ "dojox", "/Dojo/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojox" ],
        [ "dynamicChart", "../dynamicChart" ]
    ]
}
```

demo.css

```
@import "/Dojo/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
@import "/Dojo/dojo-release-1.6.1/dijit/themes/dijit.css";
@import "/Dojo/dojo-release-1.6.1/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";

.dojoxLegendNode {border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px; padding: 3px}
.dojoxLegendText {vertical-align: text-top; padding-right: 10px}
```

I'm not putting src.js. it doesn't change anything.
Would anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely,

Nancy

Comment: It's difficult to answer this without more information. Is the dropdown being rendered? Is changePlot being called at all? Have you removed anything from demo.html? Have you tried putting debug statements in src.js to see where it fails?

Comment: when you click the 1st URL that I provided you would understand what I'm trying to do. You know, I need to 1, rendering the same page with all these charts with conditions; 2, changing the data with my data. Now i can't even achieve the 1st scope.

Comment: actually I've been able to get it run but where I could change some looks and put my own data? Where the function changePlot() is hiding?

Comment: changePlot and all the other logic is in src.js. If you need to make changes to it, you should change the reference in demo.html where it says "src.js" to src.js.uncompressed.js", and make your changes in the latter.

Comment: src.js(uncompressed.js) also contains the "data". But as you'll see, it's just a loop that generates random values, since this is just a demo.

Comment: Thank you, Frode. Lemme try, I guess you just answered my question.. lemme try. Also, I didn't know they compress js stuff.

Comment: Thank you, Frode. Now I know where I should put my own code in. One more question, is this only way that I need to use dojo_src.zip but dojo.zip??? I can accomplish this only by using dojo-release-172-src. Is this weird? it just doesn't work in the compressed version. maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with this way. 
__download dojo-release-1.7.2-src and create a project in Eclipse. Then deploy it into tomcat.
I don't know why it doesn't work if i use dojo-release-1.7.2. 
In src.js, I can do some change with my own data:

```
var getData = function(){
    var data = new Array(size);
    for(var i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        data[i] = Math.random() * magnitude;
    }
    return data;
};
```